# How can you handle rewrite rules for custom post types with option to filter on custom taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have seen [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/custom-post-type-archives-by-date-and-taxonomy) but can't wrap my head around actually filtering on the taxonomy as well..

Essentially what I'm looking for is an archives page for the taxonomy such as mysite.com/movies (which the previous question answers), but to filter on custom taxonomy within the custom post type such as Settings => New York, Berlin so that you can use links such as mysite.com/movies/new-york.

Any pointers as to what my rewrite rules should be would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've used in the past for a similar requirement;

```
register_post_type('movie', array(
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie')
));

register_taxonomy('movie_location', 'movie', array(
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies')
));

/**
 * Add rewrite rules for 'base' archives.
 * @param object $r Instance of {@see WP_Rewrite}
 */
function my_custom_rewrite_rules(&$r)
{
    $rules = array(
        'movies/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'post_type=movie&paged=' . $r->preg_index(1),
        'movies/?$' => 'post_type=movie'
    );

    foreach ($rules as &$rule)
        $rule = $r->index . '?' . $rule;
    $r->rules = array_merge($rules, $r->rules);
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

See the `rewrite` argument in `register_taxonomy()`? WordPress automatically creates the appropriate rewrite rules, including archive pagination!

Also note the singular use of `movie` in the `register_post_type()` `rewrite` argument - partly because, IMO, it's semantically correct, but more so that you don't open up a whole can of worms.

What's that can of worms exactly?

Well, otherwise you'll end up with two rewrite rules like so;

```
'movies/([^/]+)/?$' => 'post_type=movie&movie_location=$matches[1]'
'movies/([^/]+)/?$' => 'post_type=movie&name=$matches[1]'
```

Whichever one is indexed first in the rewrite rules array will always be triggered, and **the other one ignored**.

So say you've a got a movie named `made-in-britain`, but the rewrite rule for the taxonomy archive comes first, WordPress is always gonna look for movies with the `made-in-britain` term, rather than the movie itself!