# Why doesnt my tag page populate with this custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, attachments, tags, mysql

I have a tag page that is generated with the first image attachments from all of the posts.  I call it in the loop with :

```
<img src="<?php echo get_first_attachment() ?>" />
```

and this is the function :

```
function get_first_attachment(){
    $querystr =
    "
        SELECT
                wp_posts.post_excerpt AS 'imageTitle',
                wp_posts.guid AS 'imageGuid'
        FROM
            wp_posts
        WHERE
                wp_posts.post_parent = ".get_the_ID()."
            AND wp_posts.post_type = \"attachment\"
        ORDER BY \"menu_order\"
        LIMIT 1
    ";
    global $wpdb;
    $url = get_bloginfo('url');
    $post_item = $wpdb->get_row($querystr);
    $first_attachment = $post_item->imageGuid;
    $not_broken = @fopen("$first_attachment","r"); // checks if the image exists
    if(empty($first_attachment) || !($not_broken)){ //Defines a default image
        unset($first_attachment);
    }else{
        $first_attachment = str_replace($url, '', $first_attachment);
    }
    return $first_attachment;
}
```

This works great with regular posts but not my custom post types. Which are in the post_type portfolio.

```
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments','trackbacks','revisions','custom-fields','page-attributes','thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'tags')
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}
```

Looking at the tables Both post and portfolio share post_type = attachment, however different in that one has post_type = post and the other = portfolio.

I do not understand the SELECT .. post_excerpt is a blank column and guid is just full of urls.  I am confused.  Thanks for any help.

I figured out that the image attachment has nothing to do with it, my custom post type is not being included in the tag loop... I will post more code once I figure out what it is I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to get rid of custom query altogether. Try something like:

```
$attachments = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
  'numberposts' => 1,
));
```

Comment: thanks.. I can not get anything to work with that. Can you please elaborate

Comment: @zac does query like in my answer (maybe needs tweaking) return anything for you? It should get you first attachment that has current post as parent.

Comment: It returns the images, but not to a specific tag, and not from the custom posts.  My original question I was able to pull attachments for just those tags, but it did not work with my custom post type

Comment: @zac sorry, I am not following. Your custom query searches for attachments that have current post in the loop as parent (`get_the_ID()`). It has nothing to do with tags.

Answer (score 0):

Of course after I offer up a bounty I immediately find the answer.  It just took me a while to figure out what the question was...  It seems that custom post types are not designed to work in archives like this.  I did find a function the allows this to work:

[Custom Post Type Archives by Date and Taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/custom-post-type-archives-by-date-and-taxonomy)

Comment: That question/answers are very outdated. Custom Post Types got archive support since WP 3.1, see `has_archive` when registering and such.